# MySQL INSERT IGNORE / ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE not detecting duplicates

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I'm having an issue here, and after 2 hours of Googling Stackoverflow answers and testing different ideas I can't figure it out. Hopefully it's a no-brainer for someone out there.

**EDIT: Fixed! See solutions below.**

*Here is my code:*

```
// Establish Table and vars
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pages(page varchar(255), content varchar(255))");
$page = 'Hello'; $content = 'This is the content.';

// Ive tried this:
mysql_query("INSERT INTO pages SET page='$page' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE content='$content'");

// Ive also tried:
mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO pages SET page='$page', content='$content'"));
mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO pages SET page='$page'")); // No content
```

*Expected result:* Create one row with 'page' value of 'Hello' ('content' value of 'This is the content.'). When script is run a second time, no additional row is created, because there is already a row with 'page' value of 'Hello'.

*Observed Result:* Every time script is run, a new row with page value of 'Hello' is created, assumedly because this is not a duplicate key. Buy why not? I have tried creating a table with an ID field that is AUTO_INCREMENT and the primary key, but I thought that was causing the problem so I simplified it.

*(That code was:)*

```
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pages(id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, page varchar(255), content varchar(255), primary key (id))");
```

*Desired Result:* A new row should be inserted into the table if there is no row with a 'page' field of 'Hello.' Once this has been created, running the same script again should NOT result in a new row.

Thank you!

**EDIT: Fixed! See solutions below.**

My solution:

```
// Table needs a primary key to search for duplicates.
    mysql_query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pages(page varchar(255), content varchar(255), primary key (page))"); // Establish Table
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `page` field needs to be a PRIMARY KEY or have a UNIQUE index on it for ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE to work. Try:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pages(page varchar(255), content varchar(255), primary key (page))
```

Comment: Yup, this is the one! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As the query says... on duplicate **KEY**. that only triggers if the insert would violate a unique constraint on the table. if there's no keys, the DB will not scan the entire table to see if there's a duplicate.